# Multiple single onClick events

Tags: javascript

I'm just messing around on JavaScript. I want to create two single on-click buttons, each which serve separate functions. However, the first button's response is always that of the second if that group of code is in. It works fine independently.

I've double checked online and tried a few functions, but everything comes back to multiple-function buttons.
I'm not super advanced and I just do random programming for fun.

If the yes button is clicked, then "Good" should appear. If the no button is clicked, then "Bad" should appear. 
When both groups of code are together, "Bad" is always shown, regardless of the button shown. If only the first group of code is isolated, then the result is "Good".

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Good";
  var result = str.link("https://www.allrecipes.com/search/results/?wt=authentic%20taco%20recipes&sort=re");
  document.getElementById("happy").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>               
<button onclick="myFunction()">No</button>

<p id="sad"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Bad";
  var result = str.link("https://www.tacobell.com/");
  document.getElementById("sad").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
Do you like tacos?
<br />                 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Yes</button>

<p id="happy"></p>
```

Comment: You can't use the same name for both functions.

Comment: You should put all of your script at the bottom of your document and make sure the functions have different names. Just call different functions when you click different buttons and it should work as you expect.

Comment: That's because the second function which has the same name, overrides the behavior of the first one, use 2 differents names and you will be fine :)

Comment: There is only 1 function, both buttons call the same function

Comment: [`.link()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link) is deprecated btw, better use an alternate method

Answer (score 0):

You should name your function differently:

In fact when you declare the second function in your original code it overwrites the first one because they have the same name.

```js
function myGoodFunction() {
  var str = "Good";
  var result = str.link("https://www.allrecipes.com/search/results/?wt=authentic%20taco%20recipes&sort=re");
  document.getElementById("happy").innerHTML = result;
}

function myBadFunction() {
  var str = "Bad";
  var result = str.link("https://www.tacobell.com/");
  document.getElementById("sad").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
Do you like tacos?
<br />                 
<button onclick="myGoodFunction()">Yes</button>

<p id="happy"></p>

               
<button onclick="myBadFunction()">No</button>

<p id="sad"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a single click event function for both of your buttons.
See below code -

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
  var btnHtml = elem.innerHTML;
  var str = "Good";
  var id = "happy"
  if(btnHtml == "No"){
    str = "Bad";
    id = "sad";
  }
  
  var result = str.link("https://www.allrecipes.com/search/results/?wt=authentic%20taco%20recipes&sort=re");
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
Do you like tacos?
<br />                 
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Yes</button>

<p id="happy"></p>
           
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">No</button>

<p id="sad"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, one function for both `onclick` events.

HTML

```
<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction('yes')">Yes</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('no')">No</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction(value)
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=value;
}
```

Here's the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/840Larsn/

Comment: where is the link gone ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using `Function` constructor and the functions are created in the global scope and therefore the second function overwrites the first one.

You can refer to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Difference_between_Function_constructor_and_function_declaration) to see the definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery if you wish,its simple

```js
$('.clickbtn').click(function(e){
var str,result ;
var data = $(this)
if(data.attr('data-id')==1)
{
   str = "Good";
   result =     str.link("https://www.allrecipes.com/search/results/?wt=authentic%20taco%20recipes&sort=re");
   $("#text").html(result) 
}

else
{
  str = "Bad";
  result = str.link("https://www.tacobell.com/");
  $("#text").html(result)
}


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Do you like tacos?
<br />                 
<button class="clickbtn" data-id=1>Yes</button>
<button class="clickbtn" data-id=2>No</button>
<p id="text"></p>
```